# Toggle attributes between Two Buttons with a click event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a container with 2 button elements inside of them. Both buttons have the same class name but different attribute values (`size`).

I have wrapped the buttons in a forEach property and added a click event listener.

Once the event is executed, I am using `setAttribute('active', '')` on the selected button, but when the other is clicked, it should remove the attribute from the old event, and add it to the current one.

#### Current situation:

It sets an `active` attribute on both buttons, but doesn't remove the inactive ones.

#### Expected result:

The `active` attribute should be only enabled when I click on the selected button.

#### Here's a basic snippet:

```js
const getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

getButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.setAttribute('active', '')
    console.log(button.getAttribute('size'))
    });
  })
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="test" size="10">Press Me 10</button>
  <button class="test" size="20">Press Me 20</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go deeper. :)

You can use `forEach` inside an `forEach`

```js
getButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getButtons.forEach(b => {
       //remove all active attributes
       b.removeAttribute('active')
    })
    // add single active attribute
    button.setAttribute('active', '')
    console.log(button.getAttribute('size'))
    });
  })
```

But actually `the best way is always native` - using `radio buttons` may be the best solution, because in radio button group there can be only one active button

Answer (score 1):

use jquery `toggle()`

```
const getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
    
getButtons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
button.toggle("active", function() {
console.log(button.getAttribute('size'))
   });      
  });
})
```

Comment: Im not using jQuery though

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the active attribute from buttons before applying active to new button. :)

```
getButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  document.querySelectorAll("button[active]").forEach(button => button.removeAttribute('active'))
    button.setAttribute('active', '')
    console.log(button.getAttribute('size'))
    });
  })
```